# Change Date object from EST to PST (one example) without offset then alter it to UTC with offset. Without library support

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

**Scenario:**

Using Google Forms, a user enters a date and a time and a timezone in different fields. Google forms then outputs to Google Sheets.

I end up with a date and time combined in one column, and the three character representation of a timezone (EST, PST, CST). This gets passed to a trigger script to pass data to an external source.

**Problem:**

Google Sheets, defaults the date time combination to whatever that Column is set to in sheets. Which if unset is EST it seems. So whether the user filling out the form says for example: 05/05/2020 17:00:00 and they select PST from the other form field. The script will get a date/time object that contains the correct time, but its setup with EST.

**The desired outcome**

I want to take the correct date/time 05/05/2020 17:00:00 and change the timezone on it to PST in this example without applying an offset to it. So I can then ultimately take that date/time and apply an offset for UTC to it, so it represents the time the user input, while fulfilling the needs from storage of that data needs.

TLDR;

- I need to take a Timestamp in EST 05/05/2020 17:00:00
- Convert it to PST 05/05/2020 17:00:00 (so the date/time stays the same)
- So I can then change it to equal UTC 05/06/2020 01:00:00

Without the use of a library like moment.js I need this to be pure javascript.

Comment: If you know the offset for the initial date, you can create a Date object that is UTC and from there use [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with the *timeZone* option to get a timestamp in any timezone that has an IANA representative location. However, places that observe US EST also observe daylight saving since sometime in the 20th century, and prior to 1900 likely had an offset that was not -8. So you need to accommodate historic changes too (which the *timeZone* option does).

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult thing to achieve with native JavaScript Dates... but maybe not impossible.

I'd suggest creating a `formatISODateWithOffset()` function that takes year, month, day etc. arguments along with a timezone to specify a given date in a certain location.

Once this timestamp is created, it can be parsed easily using the Date class and converted to any other timezone using [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

We can then convert the LA time to UTC time by using Date.UTC() and subtracting the relevant offset.

```js
function zeroPad(n, length = 2) {
    return String(n).padStart(length, '0');
}

function formatISODate(year, month, day, hour, minute, second = 0) {
    return `${year}-${zeroPad(month)}-${zeroPad(day)} ${zeroPad(hour)}:${zeroPad(minute)}:${zeroPad(second)}`;
}

function formatISODateWithOffset(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZone) {
    let isoDate = formatISODate(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    let offset = findUTCOffsetMinutes(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZone);
    return isoDate + formatOffset(offset);
}

function formatOffset(minutes) {
    const hours = (Math.floor(Math.abs(minutes) / 60) + '').padStart(2, '0');
    const mins = ((Math.abs(minutes) % 60) + '').padStart(2, '0');
    return (minutes < 0 ? '-': '+') + hours + ':' + mins;
}

function findUTCOffsetMinutes(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZone) {
    const iso = formatISODate(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    for(let offsetMinutes = -720; offsetMinutes <= 720; offsetMinutes += 30) {
      const isoWithOffset = iso + formatOffset(offsetMinutes);
      const localTime = new Date(isoWithOffset).toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone } );
      if (localTime === iso) {
        return offsetMinutes;
      }
    }
    return null;
}

function convertISODate(iso, timeZone) {
    return new Date(iso).toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone } );
}

let year = 2020;
let month = 5;
let day = 5;
let hour = 17;
let minute = 0;
let second = 0;

let nyTime = formatISODateWithOffset(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 'America/New_York');
let laTime = formatISODateWithOffset(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 'America/Los_Angeles');

let laOffset = findUTCOffsetMinutes(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 'America/Los_Angeles');
let utcTime = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second) - laOffset * 60000);

console.log('New York time:   ', nyTime)
console.log('Los Angeles time:', laTime)
console.log('UTC time:        ', utcTime.toISOString())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I realize you don't wish to use libraries, however, just to show how this can be done with [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#luxon), I've added an additional snippet. As you can see, this is very straightforward using this module.

```js
let { DateTime } = luxon;

let dtNewYork = DateTime.local(2020, 5, 5, 17, { zone: 'America/New_York' });
console.log('New York time:   ', dtNewYork.toISO())

let dtLa = DateTime.local(2020, 5, 5, 17, { zone: 'America/Los_Angeles' });
console.log('Los Angeles time:', dtLa.toISO())

let dtUTC = dtLa.setZone('UTC');
console.log('UTC time:        ', dtUTC.toISO())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: In Safari, the third example in the first code block returns “Invalid DateZ”. Instead of creating a timestamp that is then parsed by the built-in parser, why not just pass that values directly to *Date.UTC*, adjusting the hours and minutes for the offset as required?

Comment: My problem I discovered, is when google sheets sends something to app scripts, it takes the date from the column in the sheet and applies an offset based on the setting of the form before it sends the data to the script. So the Date time I get is already thrown off, but doesn't match what I need it to based on the data passed down from the form to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you really need to transform dates and times. GSheets is a collaborative tool, make sure the scripters timezone is correct for all people (the default is sometimes New York!).

[image]

Comment: I do, that setting will transcribe the date to whatever that setting is. So if i set it to that, and it sends to app scripts from there it takes the physical time in the column and transforms it to the equivelent offset, which is not what i need, I need the actual time/date provided in the column before google transforms it to match the setting

Comment: A user will enter a time/date in one column, and say whether or not its in a given timezone in another. This is a limitation from the Google Form that feeds the Google Sheet